# Is there a way of catching all unrecognised command line flags using Go's `flag` package?

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I'm currently writing a wrapper around `git diff`, and it would be nice if any flag that wasn't immediately relevant to my program would be passed through to `git diff`. So for example:

- Running `my-tool` eventually runs `git diff`
- Running `my-tool --dir` eventually runs `git diff --dir`

I'm using the [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package for parsing command line flags, however, and it looks like there's no option to collect unrecognised flags. I've also investigated the [`pflag`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/pflag) package, which has the [ability to keep running when encountering an unknown flag](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/pflag#ParseErrorsWhitelist), but doesn't appear to offer a way to collect these unrecognised flags.

My question is -- is there a way of parsing flags that also allows collection of unrecognised flags, short of copying one of these implementations and modifying it?

Comment: No, there is not.  A workaround is to define a flag containing flags for for the `git diff` command.  See the `go build` flags `-gcflags`, `-asmflags`, etc. as an example.  Another workaround is to pass `git diff` flags after `--` so they are handled as arguments.

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón! Hadn't thought of the `--` option; that could work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I]s there a way of parsing flags that also allows collection of unrecognised flags, short of copying one of these implementations and modifying it?

No.

Comment: Shouldn't "answers" like this be a Q comment?